# www prefix not working

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, cname-record

The "www" prefix for my domain  is not working, even after updating the DNS zone by adding www as a cname of mydomain.com, or adding www as a A record with the actual server IP address. As it is a dedicated server I even added the ServerAlias line on Apache, but still none of the solutions worked. Any ideas?

Additional information: on intodns.com, the "www" section says:

```
WWW A Record     Your www.mydomain.com A record is:
www.mydomain.com -> www.mydomain.com -> www.mydomain.com -> [ cname_error  ] 

[Looks like you have CNAME's]
```

Cheers,
Nicolas.

Comment: Problem fixed: it was  actually an NS issue; the changes weren't applied then ><

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a lot of technical information about what you are doing or working with.  However I would start with pinging the host.  Is that working (forget about apache for the moment)?

If not then check how you entered the hostname, some configurations want just www and the ip address and some systems want the full www.mydomain.com

To me the error you got reads that you have a looping lookup.  One CNAME pointing to another.  Just have the www as an A record as a start.

Comment: I do agree with you an the looping, but I can't figure it out. I can ping the server mydomain.com, but not www.mydomain.com When you talk about the hostname, you mean on the DNS zone from the DNS provider?

Comment: +1, Start with just setting up a A record.

Comment: Done, but I have to wait then. How do I know when this is working? Is there any website that read all the DNS information?